# Wordpress- WIth Pie Register Plugin how can define User Role?

Tags: wordpress

Pie Register Plugin how can define User Role?

I need to define a specic role for Pie Register Plugin.
If anyone know this way please let me know.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah I got the solution.
Edit Plugin and set role instead of default_role
And Its working.

Comment: In which file we need to change can you please help me on this..?

Answer (score 1):

Change role option is available, but in hidden mode, not sure if this is bug of Pie register plugin or they have hide it intentionally, you can enable section from inspect area.
[check screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spHVh.png)

Ref: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/registration-form-not-obeying-wp-default-role-setting/